# Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <UINavigationController: 0x2007af00>

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am getting the following error:

```
Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <UINavigationController: 0x2007af00>.
```

On the following code:

```
-(void) showAddressBookDialog
{
    [self presentMailComposeViewController:nil];
}


- (void)presentMailComposeViewController:(NSString *)recipient {
    // Create the compose email view controller
    MFMailComposeViewController *composeEmailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [composeEmailViewController setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    [composeEmailViewController setSubject:@"Join me on X"];
    [composeEmailViewController setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:recipient, nil]];
    [composeEmailViewController setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:YES];
    [composeEmailViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    self.inviteFriendsMailComposerVC_ = composeEmailViewController;
    //[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:composeEmailViewController animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:composeEmailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    [composeEmailViewController release];
}
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder why you are dismissing you view first... remove this line from your method

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Its better to check first whether the device is configured to send email. See this [link](http://ioscoderef.blogspot.com/2012/09/using-inapps-email-for-ios-in-xcode.html)

Answer (score 0):

`navigationController` is a property of all `UIViewControllers` which gives you their parent navigation view controller, if one exists. It sounds like you never added  `yourviewController` to a navigation controller's stack of view controllers.